# Similes that do not make use of like or as

Tags: metaphors, simile

Is it possible to have a simile that does not contain the words 'like' or 'as'?

Would the following sentence exemplify such a simile?:

> He was handsome in a way that required a bit of work from the viewer.

Or is this a metaphor?

Comment: It's neither a metaphor nor a simile.  You aren't comparing (simile) nor equating (metaphor) his handsomeness to some other thing.

Comment: Just take any simile with “like” and replace it with “in the same way that”

Comment: @Jim can you give an example of a simile in which that replacement works? I can't think of one. In particular, I am thinking of "she was like a breath of fresh air." The resulting *she was in the same way that a breath of fresh air* makes no sense. How about "she ran like the wind"? Close, but not quite: *she ran in the same way that the wind* makes no sense, but you can make is grammatical by adding another verb: *she ran in the same way that the wind runs.* It's grammatical but still nonsensical.

Comment: His face was a full moon of shininess. Her hands were butterflies on the piano keys. Your questions are fireflies in the night. Her honesty was a beacon in the night. Her voice rang shrilly down the hall.  Those are examples of metaphors. Comparing things to other things without like or as.

Comment: I'm with phoog. In spite of all Lambie's efforts, I don't think there's any difference at all between 'His face was a full moon of shininess' and 'His face was like a full moon of shininess'.

If the question was really on a level that made that difference worth noting, what was the point, please?

Comment: At ELU level, a metaphor compares point/s of resemblance in a tenor (the thing/person being described) and the vehicle (the hopefully helpful metaphorical 'look-alike'). Similes are a formulaic way of writing metaphors, using 'as ... as ...', 'like ...'. // I'd struggle to count 'He was tenacious in the way bulldogs are' in or out of {metaphors}. And it's formulaic.

Answer (score 4):

If you are simply looking for a way to express that something is like something else in some way, without using the word like or as, I think Jim's comment from a couple of months ago is on point. For example, instead of saying

> He was as wild as the west wind.

you could say

> He was wild in the same way that the west wind is wild.

or (somewhat differently)

> His wildness was the wildness of the west wind.

In neither case is the reader likely to take literally the assertion that a person's wildness and a wind's wildness are really the same. Instead the reader will be inclined to read the asserted sameness as a simile-like likeness.

Similarly, if you reword

> He was running around like a chicken with its head cut off.

as

> He was running around the way a chicken with its head cut off might have done.

you express the same idea of similarity without using *like* or *as*.

Usually, the *like* or *as* form is less long-winded and thus more appealing to the reader's or listener's ear because it's more concise. But if the task is to express the substance of a simile without using *like* or *as*, it can certainly be done by using some form of "in the same way that" or "the way."

Having said that, I agree with John Feltz's comment that

> He was handsome in a way that required a bit of work from the viewer.

is neither a simile nor a metaphor. And neither is

> He was as handsome as he could be, given that he depended on the lively imagination of others to make him seem attractive.

Comment: +1 but perhaps we should up the ante and add "way" to "like" and "as".

Comment: Yes, 'in the way that X is' is equally formulaic. What exactly a simile is is a matter of definition (and not all that clear), but linguists include all similes in the set of metaphors.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth *The fog comes
on little cat feet.

It sits looking
over harbor and city
on silent haunches
and then moves on.*

Answer (score 0):

Rather, just insert “is similar to” for “like” and you have a simile.  For example, “she ran similar to the wind.”  This is a simile because it makes a comparison rather than claiming that she actually is the wind in the manner of a classic metaphor.

Comment: Hello, Prof.G. On ELU, the linguist's definition of 'metaphor', which includes all similes, is standard,

Answer (score 0):

While a simile is most often described as a comparison using the words "like" or "as," this description is for simplicity's sake and is intended as a handy means of identifying MOST similes. This description wasn't intended to be a definition or a requisite feature of a simile. Think of it the same as adverbs ending in "-ly" or 'i' coming before 'e' except after 'c.' There will be exceptions. To paraphrase Dave Chappelle as Rick James: English is a helluva language.

Short answer: Yes, there are numerous ways to have a simile without "like" or "as." Saying something is "similar to" something else comes to mind. As long as there's a direct comparison between 2 unlike things. And what people mean when by "direct" or "explicit" is that the sentence is telling you that it's making a comparison, rather than letting you intuit that fact. "Like" and "as" are the easiest ways to do that, but as long as you are informing the reader that a comparison is going on, it's a simile. Indirect or implicit comparisons, the reader has to discern from context and semantics that there is a comparison.

Comment: Hello, Gaius. On ELU, the unfortunate distinction between simile and metaphor perpetuated in many schools is not accepted. Any comparison between certain features of otherwise unlike people / things / situations ... is termed a metaphor. A simile is the subset of these using set formulas (as bold as brass; crazy like a fox; like a red, red rose ...). At least one site dealing with acceptable English insists that the word 'as' or the word 'like' be present. If you wish to offer a different use of the term, a respectable authority supporting this is required on ELU.

Comment: *This description wasn't intended to be a definition or a requisite feature of a simile* certainly needs a citation. Not intended by whom? It seems to be intended by the million primary school teachers who teach exactly the definition that a simile requires "like" or "as", and mark students incorrect who differ from that. But, allowing for the fact that teachers are often wrong, who in your opinion actually decided on the definition of "simile" and managed to enforce it? And how?

Comment: My apologies. Perhaps I was taught wrong that the distinction is explicit/direct versus implicit/indirect. I understand that technically they are all metaphors but, colloquially, people describe them separately. If someone asked what makes humans different from animals, pointing out that human beings are animals just seems pedantic and removed from the focus, albeit technically correct.

Comment: I'm clearly far from alone in thinking this, and the thing about grammatical rules, style guides, and dictionaries is that they're descriptive, not prescriptive.

Tons of teachers teach the Bohr model of the atom, too. Teachers use simplifying shortcuts all the time. Shortcuts that frequently give the wrong idea or oversimplify.

Comment: Most dictionaries appear to refer to the use of "like" or "as" in similes with words such as "often" and "usually," with Webster's New World College Dictionary stating, “…by the use of like, as, etc.” In fact, of the 6 dictionaries I checked, Cambridge was the only standout, stating, “…always including the words "as" or "like."”

And for your citation, more definitions to follow…

Dictionary.com:
 - A figure of speech in which two unlike things are explicitly compared.

Merriam-Webster:
 - A figure of speech comparing two unlike things that is often introduced by like or as.

Comment: Cambridge:
 - (The use of) an expression comparing one thing with another, always including the words "as" or "like."

Collins:
 - A figure of speech that expresses the resemblance of one thing to another of a different category, usually introduced by “as” or “like.”

Webster’s New World College Dictionary:
 - A figure of speech in which one thing is likened to another, dissimilar thing by the use of like, as, etc.

Comment: Oh, and here's Merriam-Webster on simile vs. metaphor, in which it describes a metaphor as being "used in place of something." A trait not shared with similes, suggesting separate and distinct categories, not a subset. (Also echoed in definitions of metaphor.):
“Simile comes from the Latin word "similis" (meaning “similar, like”), which seems fitting, since the comparison indicated by a simile will typically contain the words as or like. Metaphor, on the other hand, comes from the Greek word "metapherein" (“to transfer”), which is also fitting, since a metaphor is used in place of something.”